# Pushing data from json object to ko.obsrvablearray()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, jet

I want to push some field from json object that look like that

```
{
  "type": "tasks",
  "levels": 3,
  "links":    [
        {
            ....
        }   

     ],
     "assignedDate": "2017-08-02 16:03:36",
     "number": 200612,
     "priority": 3,
     "createdDate": "2017-08-02 16:03:36",
     "state": "ASSIGNED",
     "ownerRole": "LoanApplication.Process Owner",
     "processName": "LoanProcess",
     .
     .
     .

}
```

in  **ko.observableArray**. this is my JS code (i am using oracle jet )

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'ojs/ojtable'], function (oj, ko) {
    function homeContentViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.data = ko.observableArray();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8085/get/bpm").
            then(function (taches) {
                $.each(taches, function () {
                    self.data.push({
                        title: this.type,
                        releaseYear: this.levels,
                        director: this.title
                    });
                });
            });




    self.dataSource = new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(
            self.data, 
            {idAttribute: 'title'}
    );
    }
    return homeContentViewModel;
   });
```

ps: when i change the JSON object to a JSON array it work 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? Is `taches` an array of objects, or is it just the object?

Comment: taches is just the object

Comment: If `taches` is an object, it doesn't make sense to call `$.each`. You'll have to do `self.data.push({
                        title: taches.type,
                        releaseYear: taches.levels,
                        director: taches.title
                    });`. If this is the actual fix, there should be an error message in your console...

Comment: @user3297291 thank you a lot it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user3297291 this one worked

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'ojs/ojtable'], function (oj, ko) {
function homeContentViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.data = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8085/get/bpm").
        then(function (taches) {

                self.data.push({
                    title: this.type,
                    releaseYear: this.levels,
                    director: this.title
                    });
        });




self.dataSource = new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(
        self.data, 
        {idAttribute: 'title'}
   );
   }
   return homeContentViewModel;
});
```

Comment: The above will work fine, but if you were to do it with the forEach loop in the future, I suggest one adjustment. Push the getJSON results into a temp array and then update the self.data observable "once".  The reason for this is, that as you have it now, the knockout observable is sending out an event every time you do that push.  It can lead to bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Model(opt_data) {
    var data        = opt_data || {};
    var self        = this;
    self.taches     = ko.observableArray([]); // with ([])

    for (var i = 0; i < data.taches.length; i++) {
        var tache = new Tache(data.taches[i]);
        self.taches.push(tache);
    }
}

function Tache(opt_data) { 
    var data = opt_data || {};
    var self = this;

    self.title       = ko.observable(data.type   || "");
    self.releaseYear = ko.observable(data.levels || "");
    self.director    = ko.observable(data.title  || "");
}

var vm = new Model(dataJson); //Your json with some data
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```